# Get child elements in xml with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file that I need to parse through and get values. Below is a snippit of xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<mobile>
  <userInfo>
  </userInfo>
  <CATALOG>
    <s0>
      <SUB0>
        <DESCR>Paranormal Studies</DESCR>
        <SUBJECT>147</SUBJECT>
      </SUB0>
    </s0>
    <sA>
      <SUB0>
        <DESCR>Accounting</DESCR>
        <SUBJECT>ACCT</SUBJECT>
      </SUB0>
      <SUB1>
        <DESCR>Accounting</DESCR>
        <SUBJECT>ACCTG</SUBJECT>
      </SUB1>
      <SUB2>
        <DESCR>Anatomy</DESCR>
        <SUBJECT>ANATOMY</SUBJECT>
      </SUB2>
      <SUB3>
        <DESCR>Anthropology</DESCR>
        <SUBJECT>ANTHRO</SUBJECT>
      </SUB3>
      <SUB4>
        <DESCR>Art</DESCR>
        <SUBJECT>ART</SUBJECT>
      </SUB4>
      <SUB5>
        <DESCR>Art History</DESCR>
        <SUBJECT>ARTHIST</SUBJECT>
      </SUB5>
    </sA>
```

So, I need to grab all the child elements of `<sA>` and then there are more elements called `<sB>` etc

But I do not know how to get all of the child elements with `<sA>`, `<sB>`, etc.

Comment: [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is a better option, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$xmlstr = LoadTheXMLFromSomewhere();

$xml = new simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);

$result = $xml->xpath('//sA');

foreach ($result as $node){
  //do something with node
}
```

PHP does have a nice class to access XML, which is called [SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for a reason, consider heavily using that if your code is going to access only a part of the XML (aka query the xml). Also, consider doing queries using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/), which is the best way to do it

Notice that I did the example with sA nodes only, but you can configure your code for other node types really easily.

Hope I can help!

Answer (score 0):

you should look into [simplexml_load_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) as I'm pretty sure it would make your life a lot easier. It returns a StdObject that you can use like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(<your huge xml string>);
foreach ($xml->hpt_mobile->CATALOG->sA as $value){
    // do things with sA children 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
        $xml->load('path_to_xml');
$htp = $xml->getElementsByTagName('hpt_mobile')[0];
$catalog = $htp->getElementsByTagName('CATALOG')[0]
$nodes = $catalog->getElementsByTagName('sA')->childNodes;
```